# Receiving Cancel Signal from a Successful Request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to create some WebFilters into a Spring-Boot WebFlux Application and I noticed that all post operations I developed only worked with Actuator's endpoint, but they didn't with my own endpoints.

During my analysis I noticed that when I call an Actuator endpoint (such as: health) the Mono completed as expected. However, when I invoked my endpoint, the mono emitted a Cancel Signal. 
Is that an expected behavior?

Dependencies:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebFilter newFilter() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> chain.filter(exchange)
                                         .doFinally(signalType -> {
                                             LOGGER.info("Status: {}", signalType);
                                         })
                                         .doAfterSuccessOrError(((aVoid, throwable) -> {
                                             LOGGER.info("Only actuators come to here.");
                                         }));
    }


    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Mono<String> probe() {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> "world");
    }
}
```

```
curl http://localhost:8080/test
```

Console:
Status: cancel

```
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
```

Console:
Only actuators come to here.
Status: onComplete

I expected that all endpoint invocations would execute the doAfterSuccessOrError function, but only the actuator's Health does.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem to be a bug of SpringBoot 2.1.5, upgrade to 2.1.7 will fix this problem